# Visit org-mode links in read-only mode?

Tags: org-mode

**Q:** can I set an `org-mode` link to visit a file in read-only mode?

I want to store a link to another file in an `org-mode` document,
but, when following the link, I want `org` to visit the file in
read-only mode so that I don't go on autopilot and accidentally
edit the linked file.

Is it possible to annotate the link so `org` knows to visit it in
read-only mode?  Hypothetically:

```
[[read-only-file:somefile.txt][A file that opens in read-only mode]]
```

Comment: You can always use an elisp form (see `(info "(org) External links")`), in your case `[[elisp:(find-file-read-only "somefile.txt")][A file that opens in read-only mode]]`.

Comment: @mutbuerger: thanks!  95% of the way there, but org asks for confirmation to run the elisp.  How would one disable the confirmation request?

Comment: `org-confirm-elisp-link-function` to `nil`.

Comment: @mutbuerger: perfect!  Could you combine your comments into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use an elisp form (see `(info "(org) External links")`), in your case `[[elisp:(find-file-read-only "somefile.txt")][A file that opens in read-only mode]]`. For convenience consider setting `org-confirm-elisp-link-function` to `nil`.